# For Loop counter when looking for value in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function which creates a table based on the values of an object.

```
function buildTable (){
    //build header
    var header = "<tr><th>USERS</th>"
    for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
        header += "<th>"+groups[i]+"</th>";
    }
    header += "</tr>";

    $("#taxonomy thead").append($(header));
    //build table body
    for(var user in userGroupTable){
        var i = 0; i++;
        var row ="<tr><td>" + usersName[i] + "</td>";
        for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
            var groupName = groups[i];
            var $td = "<td>"+userGroupTable[user][groupName]+"</td>";
            row +=$td;
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        //append the data to the table
        $("#taxonomy tbody").append($(row));

    }
}
```

I'm trying to iterate between the values in the usersName array but the way it's set up the var i get's reset to 0 on every loop so the same name keeps showing up. I'm not familiar with the for( var x in array), if there some sort of counter within this I can use to iterate through my array? Or should I just set a global variable?

Sorry if the title is poor.

Comment: Try initialising `var i=0` outside of the loop? (And use a different variable, like `j`, for the inner loop)

Comment: [You should not use `for in` loops with arrays at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Oh sorry, userGroupTable is an object

Comment: But yea you guys are right. I created the variable outside the loop and called it userIndex and that fixed things. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize i before for loop, and inside for loop you are initializing i with 0,
change that to other than i

```
function buildTable (){
    //build header
    var header = "<tr><th>USERS</th>"
    for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
        header += "<th>"+groups[i]+"</th>";
    }
    header += "</tr>";

    $("#taxonomy thead").append($(header));
    //build table body
        var i = 0;
    for(var user in userGroupTable){
      i++;
        var row ="<tr><td>" + usersName[i] + "</td>";
        for(var j=0; j<groups.length; j++){
            var groupName = groups[j];
            var $td = "<td>"+userGroupTable[user][groupName]+"</td>";
            row +=$td;
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        //append the data to the table
        $("#taxonomy tbody").append($(row));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `var i` twice. Change one to a more meaningful variable name, like `userIndex`.